# Scikit-Learn Reconstruction Error in Local Linear Embedding

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

LLE : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.LocallyLinearEmbedding.html

I am trying to understand what does does sklearn mean by - "reconstruction_error_: Reconstruction error associated with embedding_"

I explored further and opened the source on github and found :
Reconstruction error for the embedding vectors. Equivalent to `norm(Y - W Y, 'fro')**2`, where W are the reconstruction weights.

Now, after going over the paper here at - [https://cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/lle/papers/lleintroa4.pdf](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eroweis/lle/papers/lleintroa4.pdf), my understanding is that the reconstruction error is given by -

[image: equation for reconstruction error]

I am confused about whether sklearn refers to the same reconstruction error or is it referring to a different quantity?